# I keep getting an error from CVS access denied due to being located out of the US...I live and am in the USA, how do I fix this?

Tags: google-chrome

This is the error message I keep getting yet I live and am in the USA. How do I fix this?

CVS.com® is not available to customers or patients who are located outside of the United States or U.S. territories. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: What does browsing to [this](https://findmylocation.org/) page show you? It might give a clue as to why you're out of the country.

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely due to use of a VPN (or *possibly* an ISP or corporate internet access that is actually outside the USA, e.g., at a border). Some work-arounds:

- Choose a VPN server inside the USA when connecting:

[image: Select VPN server]

- Don't use a VPN.
- If using a corporate portal, check with IT for the availability of an end-point inside the USA.